# Calculate the original function from a Fourier cosine series given

Tags: summation, fourier-series

Given the following cosine series

$
f(x) = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} (1-\cos(\frac{n \pi}{2}) ) \cos(\frac{n \pi x}{2})
$

Conjecture a possible closed form expression for the finction $f$ on (0,2) that is represented by this series by inspecting a few partial sum approximations.

So through using sympy, my closest plot was 
$f = 0.65 \cos(x)$
but it wasn't exact.
Is there a more mathematical way to approach it to get a more exact form?

Comment: this can be summed in terms of the dilogarithmic function, and it is not very hard if you keep their series representation in mind

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(1-cos(pi+n%2F2))cos(x+pi+n%2F2)%2Fn%5E2,%7Bn,1,inf%7D%5D

Comment: Thanks. That's really cool. Much appreciated; I've learnt something new.

Answer (score 0):

Using $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi n x)}{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-x)$$ for $0<x<2$ one gets by integration $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(\pi n x)}{n^2}= \frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2}{4}(2x-x^2)$$. 
Use this to calculate $f(x)=1-x$, only elementary transformations are necessary.